# Vim execute process in background

Tags: macos, bash, vim

I would like to run a process in the background in Vim on Mac OS X (or Unix in general).

I would hope and expect the following, or some variant, to accomplish this:

```
execute "!my_command &"
```

or

```
!my_command &
```

or

```
!my_command \&
```

or some other alternative.

Unfortunately this does not seem to execute `my_command` at all. I would expect there to be some lightweight option.

One option would be to write a wrapper script that forks the command and exits, but I'm sure someone has done that already ([GNU Parallel](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel/)?).

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Works for me in cygwin...

Comment: @n.m.: Thanks. It seems to be an escaping issue (ampersand not being properly escaped) with MacVim (and maybe only since MacVim 65?); others have encountered this in eg [FreeBSD](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ampersand_in_freebsd_shell_commands_to_view_LaTeX_files), but that solution does not work here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be because `my_command` needs a terminal to interact with. You could provide one with GNU screen or tmux, e.g.:

```
!screen -dm "my_command"
```

Or:

```
!tmux new -d "my_command"
```

Comment: Great idea. `tmux` worked as expected. Many thanks @Thor.

Answer (score 7):

All of the commands below work as expected when executed in MacVim (snapshot 66), and I'm pretty sure they would work on my Ubuntu box at home:

```
!mplayer song.mp3 &
:execute "!mplayer song.mp3 &"
:call system("mplayer song.mp3 &")
```

If it doesn't work for you, you could try one of the few scripts that allow you to run asynchronous commands:

- [AsyncCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431)
- [ShellAsync](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4182)

(and I just saw that Thor solved your problem)

Comment: Thanks romainl. At one point I could swear all the above worked for me as well, but they seem to have stopped for no apparent reason. Whatever the cause, before Thor's suggestion I also looked at the plugins you suggest but I thought they might be overkill for the given task — though the suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Did you alter the `shell` or `shellcmdflag` option?

Comment: No; they are `/bin/bash` and `-c` respectively.